# RxJS 5 Observable and variable scope aka Why is my variable unreadable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

`Angular 2 RC4` app written in `TypeScript 1.9` and `RxJS 5 beta 6`

I'm having a really hard time understanding why my class variable is not passed to the Observable generating function when I subscribe.  My code is below but you can see it running [at this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OdVy05wunfi391CBvY34?p=preview) (see `app/app.component.ts`

```
//this is the problematic var. Can't pass its updated value to the Observable
input = 'nothing'; //<- default value

ngOnInit(){//<- this runs right after class constructor
    //set to the value we want to send to the server
    this.input = 'something';
}
start(){
    //to make sure input = something when we subscribe
    this.print("Subscribing when input = "+this.input);
    this.source.subscribe(d=>this.print(d));
}
//Simulate sending input to the server
source = this.queryServer(this.input)
    .do(()=>this.print('Emitting new value...'));

//server just returns what it received
queryServer(input){return Observable.from(['Server sees '+input])}

print(value){this.log.push(value);}
log=[];
```

**output** when I start the subscription by calling `start()`

- Subscribing when input = something
- Emitting new value...
- Server sees nothing

How come even though the class property is `something` when we call subscribe, `nothing` is passed to `queryserver()`?  I tried making `input` an object such as `input={d:'something'}` thinking that maybe the problem had to do with passing values instead of references but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you are passing the default value of `input` to `queryServer` when you construct the component. Even though you change it in ngInit it has already been used to construct the pipeline that you then subscribe to. You are essentially doing the following:

```
this.input = "nothing";
const copyOfInput = this.input;
this.input = "something";
console.log(copyOfInput); //-> nothing
```

You have changed what `this.input` is pointing at but copy of it you made still points to the old value. I would posit that you actually want to initialize the pipeline in ngInit and not as part of the construction of the object.

Comment: You're right that if I compose the observable chain *after* setting `input=something` the new value is used.  This seems really limiting because if I have a model variable that changes often and I need to send the updated value to the server, do I need to re-compose the observable at every change? In the example I have here for instance, `input` will keep changing after `ngOnInit` is done. So the next time I have to call `queryServer` will I need to re-compose `source`? I find all this surprising since the Rx team makes it a point to tell us that no work is done until you call `subscribe()`

Comment: By the way, with the demo code in your answer, if `input` was really an object rather than a string, then `copyOfInput` and `input` would refer to the same thing right? That's why I expected things to work if I used objects, but the behavior I describe in the OP holds even in that case (eg: if I set `input={d:'nothing'}` when I declare the variable, and then `input.d='something'`  in `ngOnInit()`)

Comment: It's *not* doing any work until you subscribe, you are creating a pipeline that  only emits a single event when it is subscribed to, it can't track when you mutate state directly. And it it doesn't work even with the object because you use the value to create a new string which is what you actually pass to the Observable. I'll update with a suggested solution.

Comment: What I meant (about object) is that even when I pass an object (not just the string value of a property of the object), the reference is lost.  If you take another look at the bottom of my OP, you'll see that I set `input` itself to an object (it's the whole `input` that I pass to `queryServer`)

Comment: Yes, my point was that you aren't creating an `Observable` with that value you are creating it with the string `"Subscribing when input = "+this.input.d` so it doesn't matter that you are passing by reference in this case because you still create a new object that you can't track

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @paulpdaniels for the helpful input. He suggested that I compose the `source` in `ngOnInit`, after I have set `input=something`. That works for the first value of `input` but in practice `input` will continue to change after `ngOnInit` is complete, so the `source` will once again emit obsolete data.

What still really surprises me is that even when the input is an object  (rather than a simple string), the problem in the OP persists. Since objects are assigned by reference in JS, I expected differently.

The code design I opted for is to compose `source` inside a setter for `input`. That way, each time that value is set, `source` is refreshed:

```
source:Observable<any>;

_input = 'nothing';
get input(){return this._input;}
set input(val){
    this._input = val;
    source = this.queryServer(val)
        .do(()=>this.print('Emitting new value...'));
}
```

Still feels hack-y to me but I'm brand new to Observables so maybe there is no better way. If there is, I hope someone will teach it to me.